# Can not update @State variable via delegate set in View.init()

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

The following is a minimum example code with the problem.

```swift
struct TestView: View {
    @State var text = "Hello"
    let useCase = TestUseCase()

    init() {
        useCase.output = self
    }

    var body: some View {
        Text(text)
            .onAppear {
                // ① useCase.output = self
                useCase.show()
            }
    }
}
extension TestView: TestUseCaseOutput {
    func showText(text: String) {
        self.text = text
    }
}

class TestUseCase {
    var output: TestUseCaseOutput?
    func show() {
        output?.showText(text: "Changed")
    }
}
protocol TestUseCaseOutput {
    func showText(text: String)
}
```

This code changes the text from "Hello" to "Changed" when the view is displayed, but the change is not reflected. The `showText` method was called, but it had no effect. I also found that if I set the delegate at ①, the text was updated correctly.

Can anyone tell me the cause of this problem?

Comment: Change TextUseCase to a struct or an ObservableObject

Comment: You can't use `self`like that, the `View` structs are created and discarded on every state change, you need to learn value semantics before starting SwiftUI

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SwiftUI views are structs, and therefore immutable.  Whenever a SwiftUI changes, a new instance of that view struct is created.

When you update `text`, SwiftUI needs to create a new instance of `TestView`.  But, the new instance  has `text` set to `Hello` (and it was also have a new instance of `TestUseCase`) so you don't see any change.

The sequence of events is:

1. You create an instance of `TestView` - This is initialised with `text = "Hello"`
2. You update `text` which triggers SwiftUI to recreate `TestView`
3. The newly created instance of `TestView is initialised with` text = "Hello"`

In SwiftUI no object should ever need to hold a reference to a `View`.

```
init() {
    useCase.output = self
}
```

The `self` you store in your `TestUseCase` instance will be thrown away as soon as the view is updated.  It simply isn't useful to try and hold references to SwiftUI views.

You should structure your code so that views respond to changes in your model (Via `@Published` for example).  Your model should never try and update a view directly.